# Why does this uniform continuity follow from continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I'm reading a proof and it says the following:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since the mapping $\xi \mapsto e^{\imath \, \xi}$
>   is continuous, we can pick $\delta>0$ such that $$|1-e^{\imath \, x
>  (\xi-\eta)}| \leq \varepsilon$$ for any $|\xi-\eta| \leq \delta$ and
>   $x \in K.$

Why are we sure such $\delta>0$ exists? Doesn't this need some kind of uniform continuity? Also this holds for all $x$ at once?

Comment: Continuous functions on compact sets are ... ?

Comment: Yes, but that restricts my choices of elements in $K$. Here they are unrestricted? I would expect $|x-y| < \delta$ as well.

Comment: it's for $x\in K$ @user745578

Comment: $x \in K$ is not fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is compact, hence bounded. Then there is some $M > 0$ that $[-M, M] \supseteq K$. By the continuity at $0$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|y| < M \delta$, $$
|1 - \mathrm e^{\mathrm i y}| < \varepsilon. 
$$
Then for any pair $\xi, \eta$ and any $x \in K$, as long as $y = \xi -\eta$ satisfies $|y| = |\xi - \eta| < \delta $, we have $|xy| = |x(\xi - \eta)|< M\delta$, then 
$$
|1 - \mathrm e^{\mathrm i x(\xi - \eta)}| < \varepsilon. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Compact sets are bounded. So there exists $M<\infty$ such that  $|x(\xi -\eta)| \leq M |\xi-\eta |$. Now use the fact that $e^{ix}$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets. .